# EC2 how to give access to someone to setup the server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to contract a System Admin to setup my running EC2 instance.

For him to set everything up he will need my server address and my `key.perm`.

I though of setting up a new elastic IP address that I can change afterwards so that he can't access the server anymore after his work is done. But I am unsure if he can get the `Public DNS` meaning the full `xxx. compute.amazonaws.com` address once in the server?

I was wondering what's the best way to contract someone to setup your EC2 instance via SSH while taking care of your security?

Answer (score 0):

Security through obscurity - hiding the machine name/IP is never a good idea in security.
  I would after creating the instance, opening up the ssh port (in the security group), append his public key to /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys

ubuntu user by default is a sudo able user, hence he should be able to do your setup.  Once the stuff is over, delete his keys off the authorized_keys file, and this would stop him access to the ubuntu user.  Additionally I would verify that there is no backdoor setup during this process.  like, he shouldnt have created another user (sudoable or otherwise), with his keys for later login.  to defend against such attack, grep  sudo /var/log/auth.log to see all the sudo commands he has run.  be weary of things like creating new users, or running commands like bash (which can hide further root commands).  If you are happy with the commands, then you are all set.  just delete the entry in the authorized_keys file and you should be safe.